# Finding index of an element of a list of tuples with a wildcard

Tags: list, haskell, indexing, tuples, element

I am trying to find the index of an element in a list of tuples with Haskell, with the use of a wildcard.

I have adapted my types to make it easier to explain. At the moment, my way of thinking is to use elemIndex.

For example,

```
> elemIndex 2 [1,2,3,4,5]
Just 1
```

but in my case, I have a list of tuples such as this:

```
> elemIndex (2, 20) [(1, 10),(2, 20),(3, 30),(4, 40),(5,50)]
Just 1
```

I want to be able to only supply the first part of the tuple and get the index, such as this:

```
> elemIndex (2, _) [(1, 10),(2, 20),(3, 30),(4, 40),(5,50)]
Just 1
```

but the result I am getting is this:

```
<interactive>:58:15: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: Integer
    • In the expression: _
      In the first argument of ‘elemIndex’, namely ‘(2, _)’
      In the expression:
        elemIndex (2, _) [(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30), (4, 40), ....]
    • Relevant bindings include
        it :: Maybe Int (bound at <interactive>:58:1)
```

I am having trouble deciphering the error message and also cannot figure out how to workaround the error.
Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `_` is *not* a wildcard. If you use it in an expression (as in not a pattern), it is a type hole, this is normally used to give a "hint" what type to fill in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `_` is *not* a wildcard, it is a [*typed hole* [haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Typed_holes). Typed holes are often used to find out what type to fill in.

What you can use here is [**`findIndex :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:findIndex). Here instead of specifing an element to search for, you can use a predicate (`a -> Bool`), and the function will then return for a given list the first index that satisfies the predicate (wrapped in a `Just` data constructor), or `Nothing` if no element can be found.

You thus can implement this as:

```
Prelude Data.List> findIndex ((2 ==) . fst) [(1, 10),(2, 20),(3, 30),(4, 40),(5,50)]
Just 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation, it really helped me understand why its incorrect and not working